# npm conflicting peer dependency requirements installing PrimeNG into an Angular app

Tags: npm, angular8, primeng, peer-dependencies

I install primeng and get a peer dependency warning:

```
>npm install primeng --save
npm WARN primeng@9.0.2 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.10.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So I dutifully install zone.js@^0.10.2 ...

```
>npm install zone.js@^0.10.2 --save
npm WARN @angular/core@8.0.0 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

... and now it complains that I need to install zone.js@~0.9.1. If I install that it complains that zone.js@^0.10.2 needs to be installed, and so on...

What to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
I simply needed to install a prior version of primeng that depends on the same version of zone.js that my angular version (8) does.